# Laravel Passport Invalid Grant on password grant_type

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I always got invalid grant type when login .I am using Laravel 7 and passport 8.4.

I can confirm that I create the client_secret without error by running php artisan passport:install but I cant find any possibility why getting the access tokens and refresh tokens does not work.

```
 $credentials = [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => '2',
            'client_secret' => 'zcdHbITBhD5PPgGZ4n8qpIgYmmK83hcdYTbvLmja',
            'username' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
            'scope' => '*',
        ];
        $request = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST', $credentials, [], [], [
            'HTTP_Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ]);
        $response = app()->handle($request);
        //$response = app('router')->prepareResponse($request, app()->handle($request));
        $decodedResponse = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        // if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200) {
```

I am using custom user provider that correctly set in config, and I notice if I change the grant_type to 'client_credentials' it will just work, but without the refresh token which what I want.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading to latest Passport version, then run

```
php artisan passport:client --password --provider mycustomprovider
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 8.x, Passport *. If you want to get access_token and refresh_token with Password Grant Client, your $password needs to be hashed.

It worked for me

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#password-grant-tokens
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing#basic-usage